# An internal notion of freeness for complete Boolean algebras

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, boolean-algebras

### Background and Definition

Gaifman and Hales showed that there are no infinite free complete Boolean algebras.

But let a complete Boolean algebra $B$ be *internally free* if there is a set $X\subseteq B$ such that for every function $f:X\to B$, there is a unique complete endomorphism of $B$ extending $f$.

For every set $Y$, the double powerset algebra $\mathcal{PP}(Y)$ is internally free. This claim is witnessed by the set $X$ of principal ultrafilters of $\mathcal{P}(Y)$, since every function $f:X\to\mathcal{PP}(Y)$ uniquely extends to the complete endomorphism $\hat{f}$ of $\mathcal{PP}(Y)$ given by
$$\hat{f}:p\mapsto\{w\subseteq Y:\{y\in Y:w\in f({\uparrow}\{y\})\}\in p\}.$$
Here, ${\uparrow}\{y\}$ is the principal ultrafilter of $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ generated by $\{y\}$.

### The question

> Are there any internally free complete Boolean algebras which are not isomorphic to $\mathcal{PP}(Y)$, for any set $Y$? If so, how can they be informatively characterized?

### Complete Boolean algebras which are not internally free

The following are examples of complete Boolean algebras which are not internally free:

1. $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$
2. More generally, any complete atomic Boolean algebra which is not isomorphic to a double powerset algebra.
3. Any homogeneous complete Boolean algebra with more than two elements.

Exemplarily, here is a proof of item 1. Assume for contradiction that $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is internally free, as witnessed by a set $X$. Distinguish two cases:

Case 1: $X$ is finite. Then there is an atom of the subalgebra generated by $X$ with distinct elements $n$ and $m$. Let $u$ and $v$ be the corresponding principal ultrafilters of $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$. The corresponding functions mapping elements of the relevant ultrafilter to $\top$ and non-elements to $\bot$ are complete endomorphisms which coincide on $X$, contradicting internal freeness.

Case 2: $X$ is infinite. In this case, define for any set $Y\subseteq X$:
$$C(Y):=Y\cup\{-x:x\in X\backslash Y\}$$
First, for any $Y\subseteq X$, $\bigwedge C(Y)\neq\bot$; this follows from internal freeness using the function $f$ such that $f(x)=\top$ if $x\in Y$ and $f(x)=\bot$ otherwise. Second, for any distinct $Y,Y'\subseteq X$, $\bigwedge C(Y)\wedge\bigwedge C(Y')=\bot$. But since there are uncountably many $Y\subseteq X$, these two claims cannot both be true.

### A related question

A complete Boolean algebra with more than two elements which has no non-trivial complete endomorphisms is trivially internally free, as witnessed by the empty set, and non-atomic. A positive answer to the first question therefore follows from the existence of such algebras. See also the following post:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108865/are-there-complete-boolean-algebras-with-no-non-trivial-complete-endomorphisms

Comment: Do you know a complete Boolean algebra that is not internally free?

Comment: Thanks; I should have said something about that. I know that the powerset of a countable set is not internally free. I'll add this to the post.

Comment: It would be useful to have a description of what internal freeness means for Stone spaces. Of course one can use stone duality to directly translate it into a statement about stone spaces, but that doesn't seem to immediately give something nice.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the PP(Y) claim? I am a little confused, because in PP(Y) all subsets of Y are essentially indistiguishable atoms, and so how can it matter to use principal ultrafilters on P(Y) as your elements of X?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins X doesn't have to be the only set witnessing the internal freeness of PP(Y). The internal structure of the elements of P(Y) is just used as a way of specifying one such X. I've added a bit more detail above, in particular a characterization of the relevant endomorphisms. I hope this helps, or shows where I'm making a mistake.